# Access denied for user 'web'@'localhost' remote mysql

Tags: php, mysql, web, hosting

I've hosted my site and database on one VPS, but now I'm trying to migrate the website to a shared hosting, so on the VPS will remain only the database. I granted full privileges to all mysql users and also my config.php is configured to connect with the VPS's IP address but for some reason it gives me this error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

The strange thing here is that in the config.php, ["username"] is not 'root' and the ["hostname"] is not 'localhost'.

Here is the config.php

```
$db["hostname"] = "VPS's IP address";
$db["username"] = "treewee";
$db["password"] = "my MYSQL password";
$db["database"] = "web";
$db["port"] = 3306;
```

Also the `bind-address` is dissabled with # - `# bind-address="localhost"`. And yes, as I said all mysql users are granted with full privileges (including root & treewee).

In other words, I will not use MySQL provided to me by the shared hosting. However I added the VPS's IP in cPanel > Remote MySQL, but nothing... Still the same error.. Any ideas?

Sorry for my English

Comment: This is an authentication problem. You need to be sure your user has *remote* access enabled. There's separate permissions for `localhost` vs. `%` or some particular IP.

Comment: Are you sure that the $db variable is actually used for establishing connection? May be something missed and connection falling to 'root' and 'locahlost' that are both defaults.

Comment: @tadman Yes it's enabled.

Comment: @fifonik Yes, when I bought the web system, they told me that config.php is for mysql connection and etc.

Answer (score 0):

$db["username"] = "treewee" - that's the user that i use;

there is an unwanted 's in "that's", not sure if that is intentional or it's in the actual code.

What is actually trying to access the database? maybe you are using the wrong credentials, using root/localhost instead of "treewee"

Comment: Using 'root' in public website?! Huh. 'treewee' is my root mysql user. And localhost? How can I use localhost while my website is in shared hosting and my database is in VPS?